# How many files should I create for one filegroup and 9 weekly partitions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning, filegroups, datafile

I have 9 weekly partitions on one filegroup. How many files do I need to create?

There are 3 tables containing 46 million, 16 million and 10 million rows.

Comment: Are you talking about table partitioning??  If so, why are you putting all partitions on a single filegroup?  You're eliminating one of the most powerful parts of table partitioning (having filegroups on different disks, and/or make cold partitions read-only, etc.).

Comment: yes,cause the switching partition I need the staging table on the same filegroup and to avoid the drop and create staging table, prevent fragmentation, I need all partitions on one filegroup.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information to properly answer this question... What is the size of the data? What are the access patterns? What I/O subsystem is backing the database? How much RAM is allocated to the server? etc...

Comment: DB size is 400GB. RAM is 12 GB. Subscription server executes a dump every 5 minutes and the resulting file is ~1GB.

Answer (score 1):

You need one file.

Unless you have specific requirements to have multiple files, you only need one file for the filegroup. The 'specific' requirements would be things like requirement to spread the filegroup on multiple disk locations or a requirement for [round-robin allocation](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/03/07/how-many-files-should-a-database-have-part-1-olap-workloads.aspx). You did not mention any such requirement, you only give information about the number of rows in the tables, which is largely irrelevant when it comes to deciding the number of files in the filegroups.

Comment: the problem is that to correct manage partitioned table I need to create for every partition the filegroup with one file. But now for the fragmentation issue I cannot manage it in this way. And I need to know what is the correct way to create file for a lot of data.